# Can't find the correct header for a request on Windows server

Tags: asp.net, ajax, http, http-headers

I made an HTML page with some JavaScript that works fine on my laptop on Linux, but fails when I upload it on a Windows server. I think it is a header issue so I am not writing the Ajax code, but the request headers :

Ajax Request :

```
GET /index-1.html HTTP/1.1
Host: mydomain.com
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: undefined
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1553.0 Safari/537.36 SUSE/30.0.1553.0
Referer: http://mydomain.com/
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

Server Answer :

```
HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable
Content-Type: text/html
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 19 Sep 2013 19:40:44 GMT
Content-Length: 1346
```

What should I set the headers to?

Answer (score 0):

If you actually read the description of status code 406 you'll quickly find out that the problem is likely caused by "accept: undefined".